# Random PHP txt create

Tags: javascript, php, html, random, syntax-error

I have a question. I made a small project that will want to be like other text pasting an keeping software. This is the main little code:

```
fopen("text/$file.txt", "w+");

fwrite($file, $data);

fclose("text/$file.txt");
}
else {
die('No post data to process');
}
?>
```

The problem is that it gives me these errors:

```
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home/u257807476/public_html/ready.php on line 8

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/u257807476/public_html/ready.php on line 10
```

I don't know why. Please help me!

Comment: I have to specify that PHP creates my file but it just contains nothing.

Comment: let me know if you suppose to write all your  post parameters in the file

Comment: Is there any way to use .txt file breaks be shown in php? I made an example to create random .txt files by User Input and the output shows in a single line either I am using file_get_contents or import to show it. I'm using w+ to open file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `fopen` and `fclose` wrong.
Try this

```
$fileRes = fopen("test.txt", "w+");

fwrite($fileRes, 'asd');

fclose($fileRes);
```

also see function http://php.net/manual/pl/function.file-put-contents.php
`file_put_contents` which is simpler in use

Comment: Thanks. Also I had a variable with fopen function but before trying I deleted it. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Is there any way to use .txt file breaks be shown in php? I made an example to create random .txt files by User Input and the output shows in a single line either I am using file_get_contents or import to show it. I'm using w+ to open file. PS.: Sorry for duplicate.

Comment: maybe `nl2br` will help. //edit or you can use custom separator like `##newline##` that you will later change with `str_replace` to <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are posting the data and you dont know that how many parameters will be there, then you can use this code which will help you alot for wrinting all the post parameters in the key+>value form in the file.

```
$myFile = "testfile.txt";  // Open File
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");

$createStar = "****************************** \r\n";
fwrite($fh, $createStar);


$writedate = "Date : ".date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
fwrite($fh, $writedate);

$newLine = "\r\n";
fwrite($fh, $newLine);

$newLine = "\r\n";
fwrite($fh, $newLine);

$postReq1 = "Array( \r\n";
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
{
$postReq1.= "[$key] => $value \r\n";
}

$postReq1.= " )";

$PostData = "Response : ".$postReq1;        
fwrite($fh, $PostData);

$stringData = "\r\n ****************************** \r\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

close($fh);
```

Comment: Is there any way to use .txt file breaks be shown in php?
I made an example to create random .txt files by User Input and the output shows in a single line either I am using file_get_contents or import to show it.
I'm using w+ to open file.

Comment: <?php
$file = fopen("tempfile.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
?>

Comment: above code will print all the line as written in the text file.